# How to restore _restore{....} files

Tags: windows, windows-8, restore

I have lost several folders of my photos from a removable hard drive recently.  There's some _restore{...} files on it, backup files possibly?   How do I restore these to see what's in them?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind, if you have files to recover, you shouldn't do anything else before and stop all process that can write to the disk.

Good and free program to recover files is [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva).

*The `_restore {GUID}` folder contains restore points.*